# NodeJS - Different File accessible from both client and node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a (javascript) file which contains 'static' variables which are both used in the App.js and at the client side.

Unfortunately at the App.js you're required to have 'modules' which aren't used in normal jscript files. This results in an error for the client side because 'module' isn't defined. Is there any way to do this?

**TL;DR:** How can I have constant variables accessible in both app.js and at the client side?

E.g:

```
var Variable = { Foo: "Foo", Bar: "Bar"};

Variable.Foo //Accesible from both app.js and client
```

Comment: i think you ve to define your var at client or server ( one of them ) and then share it via http

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to have a file that you can load on both, client and server, and access the variables in it? If that is the case, simply first check if the `module` object exists, if so, attach the object to `module.exports`, if not, then no problem, the variables will be accessible on the browser (if they're not wrapped in an anon function).

Comment: the client is another npm-project residing on the same development environment? yes: export a simple module exposing only the object named `Variable`. no: expose the `Variable` object like the API-way via an HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

here is example using browserify:

Install browserify

```
npm install -g browserify
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g browserify
```

Write a module

```
// greetings.js
module.exports = function(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}
```

Use the module

```
// app.js
var greetings = require('./greetings');
alert(greetings('Christophe'));
```

Create the bundle

```
browserify app.js -o bundle.js
```

Add bundle.js to your index.html file and run the application.

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```